# Why I got Unable to load DLL 'libgdiplus': The specified module could not be found - CentOS 7.5

Tags: c#

codes below works properly in local dev machine..(Windows 8.1 x64)

```
   [HttpGet]
   [AllowAnonymous]
     public ActionResult TestReport(int _pid)
    {
        Reports.XtraReport _xtrareport = new Reports.XtraReport();
        _xtrareport.CreateDocument(true);
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        _xtrareport.ExportToPdf(stream);
        return  File(stream.GetBuffer(), "application/pdf");
      }
```

but it thrown exceptions below when I try on CentOS 7.5

, it thrown exceptions below:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the
>   request.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libgdiplus': The
>   specified module could not be found.
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.FunctionWrapper.get_Delegate()
>
> TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an
>   exception.
>   System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods+Gdip.GdipGetGenericFontFamilySansSerif(out
>   IntPtr fontfamily)
>
> TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BrickStyle' threw an exception.
>   DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRControlStyle..ctor()
>
> Stack  Query  Cookies  Headers DllNotFoundException: Unable to load
>   DLL 'libgdiplus': The specified module could not be
>   found.System.Runtime.InteropServices.FunctionWrapper.get_Delegate()
>   System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods+Gdip.GdiplusStartup(out IntPtr token,
>   ref StartupInput input, out StartupOutput output)
>   System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods+Gdip..cctor()
>
> Show raw exception details
>
> TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an
>   exception.System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods+Gdip.GdipGetGenericFontFamilySansSerif(out
>   IntPtr fontfamily) System.Drawing.FontFamily.GetGdipGenericSansSerif()
>   System.Drawing.FontFamily.get_GenericSansSerif()
>   System.Drawing.Font.CreateFont(string familyName, float emSize,
>   FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, byte charSet, bool isVertical)
>   DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BrickStyle..cctor()

Comment: gdiplus.dll is the unmanaged DLL on Windows that implements most of the System.Drawing functionality.  On CentOS you probably have to bring your own.  [Look here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362984/how-to-install-libgdiplus-on-centos-7) for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem with the following steps:

```
    sudo yum install yum-utils
    sudo rpm rpm --import    "http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF"
    sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo http://download.mono-  project.com/repo/centos/
    sudo yum clean all
    sudo yum makecache
    sudo yum install mono-complete
```